# Django authentication - don’t continue to ModelBackend if LDAP auth fails

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I use [django_ldap_auth](https://pythonhosted.org/django-auth-ldap/)’s LDAPBackend for real users, and Django’s ModelBackend for functional users. However, LDAPBackend creates a Django user for everyone who is able to log in, and I can set a password for that user in the Django database.

The problem is, if LDAP authentication fails for a user, but succeeds against the Django database, he can log in. This is not a desired behaviour (I think).

This could, however, come in handy if the LDAP server is not available for any reason, but only if the Django password gets updated with the LDAP password with a successful login.

My question is twofold:

- is it possible (either with my own backend or something or with django_ldap_auth itself) to save the correct password to the Django database?
- if not, is it possible to fail authentication if the LDAP server is accessible, the user is present in the LDAP database, but the password doesn’t match, even if that password matches against the Django database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-authentication-backends):

> If a backend raises a `PermissionDenied` exception, authentication will immediately fail. Django won't check the backends that follow.

So if the LDAP backend returns None, then Django will attempt to authenticate with the Model backend. However, if it raises `PermissionDenied`, then the login will fail.